# Load Images In ImageView ByDefault With Glide

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-glide

My Question is about loading image into image View With Glide. I Know How to Load Image With Glide. But I want to Create a custom ImageView so that It can Load Images By Default With Glide (To make it faster and remove memory issues by default). Is It Possible. If Yes Then How? Thank you in advance.

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {
    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    ///How to Over Ride Back Ground Attribute Sent by XML / Sent By Java Initialization
        Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.chains).into(this);

}
```

Update:
To be very simple I want To Use My Custom ImageView in my whole project Instead of Ordinary one. so that it will over come memory issues by default. In CustomImageView I want to Load Images with Glide . I'm Looking something Like

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    ///How to Over Ride Back Ground Attribute Sent by XML / Sent By Java Initialization


    @Override
    public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
        super.setBackground(background);
        Glide.with(this.getContext()).load(background).into(this);
    }


}
```

how to manage CustomImageView to work exactly like ImageView but Instead load Images With Glide.

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do . Check Targets https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/targets.html

Comment: Thank for your respponse @Raghunandan . I just want to create my Custom ImageView That will load Images By Default With Glide. Every Time when i will initialize it, Images will be loaded with Glide into that Image . I don't Have to mention Again and again . Just Write XML Like <MyCustomImageView  android:src="@drawable/img"/> so that Source img.png will load with Glide by Default.

Comment: To be very simple I want To Use My Custom ImageView Instead of Ordinary one. so that it will over come memory issues by default

Comment: try  `Glide.with(getContext())
         .load(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(),R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
                .into(new ImageViewTarget<Drawable>(this) {
                    @Override
                    protected void setResource(@Nullable Drawable resource) {
                        this.setDrawable(resource); 
                    }
                });` but i don't think you need glide for this. You can scale down your image and also do some profiling. Just because you want to avoid oom you need not use glide

Comment: @Raghunandan Thank you again. But I am very sorry I can't able to explain my problem. I have Editted My Question Please Check It.

Comment: I want to override all conditions where it need to load an image in it. including XML

Comment: use place holder for default dummy image for your image view.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public class CustomImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet set) {
        super(context, set);
        int[] attrs = {android.R.attr.background};
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(set, attrs);
        Drawable drawable = typedArray.getDrawable(0); // 0 is an index of attrs[]
        if (drawable != null) {
            setBackground(null);
            Glide.with(context).load(typedArray.getResourceId(0, placeholder_resource_id)).into(this); // 0 is an index of attrs[]
        }
        typedArray.recycle();
    }
}
```

Comment: what "typedArray.getDrawable(0); " 0 Denotes here Is it the index of Src Drawable Or Background Drawable??

Comment: 0 is index of Background Drawable because int[] attrs = {android.R.attr.background}. For Src Drawable - int[] attrs = {android.R.attr.src}